# Floating label did not show the label on input focus

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I search on the internet and found one example on how to do floating label, so I just follow exactly from what provided from the example, but when I test it on my site, it didn't work exactly as it should be. Whenever the cursor is focus on the input, the label just disappear. But it works (when on focus and blur) when the label is outside of the input. Do I miss something?

Here is the link that I follow:

[Tutorial](http://jsfiddle.net/RyanWalters/z9ymd852/)

[JSFiddle Example](http://www.bootply.com/mv2ImmuS1a#)

Here is the code:

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group input-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                <label class="control-label" for="txtUsername">Username</label>
                <input id="txtUsername" class="form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group input-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
                <label class="control-label" for="txtPassword">Password</label>
                <input id="txtPassword" class="form-control" type="password" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <button id="showOverlay" class="btn btn-default form-control" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Submit">Log In</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Site.css**

```
.control-label {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: .6;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(-340px, 8px, 0) scale(1);
    transform-origin: left top;
    transition: 300ms;
    z-index: 3;
    color: black;
}

.form-group.focused .control-label {
    transform: translate3d(-340px, 0, 0) scale(0.75);
}

.form-control {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

**Site.js**

```
$('.form-control').on('focus blur', function (e) {
    $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));
}).trigger('blur');
```

Your answer much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your problem represented in the fiddle? or is that a "working" version - it appears to be working.   It's not clear what you mean by "when the label is inside the input"

Comment: Hi, thank you for stopping by, the problem is when the cursor is on the input (focus), the label just disappear (it should be appear and scale by .25% as provided in the Tutorial link mentioned above. The fiddle version is not working version and it is my current code now in fiddle. Thanks

Comment: When I open your fiddle" (bootply) link, and click in an input, the label shrinks to about 25%.  When I leave (blur), it goes back to the original size.  It appears to be working fine.  Which browser did you use?  (worked in Chrome) Can you try on a different browser?  Is your browser zoom at 100%?  (may not make a difference)

Comment: @freedomn-m: yes, it appear to be working fine in chrome, I just opened it with chrome, but it appears the text is outside of the input (it is working fine as well in firefox whenever the text is outside of the input. When you see the Tutorial link, you will notice that even the input is empty or not and it is focused, the text will shrink about 25% from the original size. Is it because of the textbox is different?

Comment: Hi @freedomn-m, I have found the solution, it is because I haven't put the z-index when the control is focused. Thanks anyway for your time. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To one who is wondering why it didn't work, is because in the CSS, I forgot to put the `z-index` when the control is focused:

So the CSS should be (I only post the solution):

```
.form-group.focused .control-label {
    z-index: 5;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(-340px, 0, 0) scale(0.75);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed this issue in CSS.
Please check again !

```css
.control-label {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: 0.4;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(10px, 7px, 0) scale(1);
    transform-origin: left top;
    transition: 300ms;
    z-index: 3;
    color: black;
}

.form-group.focused .control-label {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(-100px, 10px, 0) scale(0.75);
}
```

Comment: Hi sorry, your code didn't work and it is because my mistake, I have post an answer. Thanks anyway.